# Matlab: How to plot without color graduation?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

My friend has made a script to handle a lot of data and plot various plots, however when he runs the script, the graphs have different colors according to the legend and when I do it, all graphs are similar with a color graduation from black to red! (see picture) Why does it differ and how do I get the graphs in different colors?

**2D plot with color graduated graphs:-**

[image: 2D plot with color graduated graphs]

```
figure
hold on
plot(sentar_7.created_at, sentar_7.acc_diff, '-');
plot(sentar_7.created_at, sentar_7.stand_toggle, '-');
plot(sentar_7.created_at, sentar_7.state, '-');
title('Sentar 7 acc')
xlabel('tid')
ylabel('dist [cm]')
legend('acc diff','stand toggle', 'state')
hold off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [is a known issue](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/278673-why-does-my-line-plot-in-matlab-show-a-color-gradient-of-black-green-and-red) with certain Intel graphics drivers. One potential workaround is to use basic hardware rendering:

```
opengl hardwarebasic
```

You could also disable the `AlignVertexCenters` property of the line object:

```
h = findall(gca, 'type', 'line')
set(h, 'AlignVertexCenters', 'off')
```

The best solution may be to update your graphics drivers to  the 4380 version.